# connect SQlite database

Tags: javascript

Im trying to view database on my web app. The problem here is that it does not view from SQLite. rather view database from chrome add-ons. Is there any way for me to view SQlite databse using Jscript?

Comment: Are you referring to the [Web SQL Database API](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/)? That has been abandoned, and [isn't well supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=sql-storage) anyway.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to directly access an arbitrary SQLite database via client side JavaScript running in a web browser.

If your database exists on a webserver, then you can write an HTTP based API (ideally one that is RESTful) and interact with it via the XMLHttpRequest object.

Comment: hello there. thank you for replying. just another question. do you need a server when you run php script?

Comment: In the context on the WWW: yes. You can also write standalone programs (that don't involve a web browser) in PHP … although it would be far from my first choice.